# Can't transfer files from Android 4.4.2 phone to eOS laptop

Tags: usb, android, mtp, elementaryos, galaxy-s3

I'm trying to transfer files from my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone which is running Android 4.4.2.  I have installed `libmtp` and have also installed a bunch of other mtp-related packages, but Elementary OS just won't detect the phone.  In fact, whenever I connect it, eOS thinks that the phone is an ethernet connection (possibly ethernet over USB).

I have tried changing the UART connection from PDA to MODEM, but that doesn't work.  I have tried enabling developer debugging on the device.  But that doesn't work, either.

When I connect the device, I see this show up in my `/var/log/syslog` file:

```
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer dbus[471]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' (using servicehelper)
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer polkitd[745]: started daemon version 0.105 using authority implementation `local' version `0.105'
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer dbus[471]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1'
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: init!
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: update_system_hostname
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPluginIfupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0, iface: wlan0)
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0, iface: wlan0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: end _init.    
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]: <info> Loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]: <info> Loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2010 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManager mailing list.
Sep  6 12:22:07 Computer NetworkManager[738]:    SCPlugin-Ofono: Acquired D-Bus service com.canonical.NMOfono
```

From the looks of it, my laptop isn't seeing the phone as an MTP device, even though the phone really does use MTP.

Currently, I've been using my wireless to transfer the files, but this has proven to be slow.  Also, I have to keep the screen on, or else the phone will disconnect from my WiFi.

So is there any way I can connect my phone to my laptop via USB so as to transfer files?